# Function 'srand' could not be solve? (i'm using Ubuntu OS and Eclipse)

Tags: c++

This is the first time i use Eclipse for C++ programming and i have an issue. I already Include "time.h" but the bug (Function 'srand' could not be solved) still appear. Please help me! Thanks so much

```
#include "iostream"
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100
void InputArray(int a[],int n)
{

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //error here Function 'srand' could not be solved
        a[0]=rand()%10; //and here 
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
            a[i]=a[i-1] + rand()%10 + 1;
}
int main() {
    int a[MAX], n;
    InputArray(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, please don't just keep adding code to the question that change it completely...

Comment: Does it really say "could not be solved"?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: @ArchDevil You're using quotes `""` instead of `<>`.

Comment: I believe `<>` are used for system/standard headers. `""` are used for your own headers.

Comment: @Mysticial yes, but I think they only matter in the order in which directories are searched.

Comment: @ArchDevil then your compiler is broken, get a better one - http://ideone.com/dmh9O

Comment: @Mysticial: `#include <...>` searches for system-defined headers. `#include "..."` first searches for non-system headers; if that fails, it searchs in the same place(s) as `<...>`. It *can* matter if there happens to be a local file called `"stdlib.h"`. `iostream`, `time.h`, and `stdlib.h` are all standard headers, and should use the `<...>` syntax.

Comment: @KeithThompson if you have your own `iostream` header, you deserve what's coming to you :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Agreed (unless you have a *very* good reason to want to hide the standard one), but using the `<...>` syntax at least eliminates one possible problem.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: sorry but if compiler is broken why it can compile other code ? :(...just junction Srand failed :(

Comment: @ArchDevil if you `#include <stdlib.h>` correctly and you still get the same error, it's the compiler. And it's `srand`, not `Srand`.

Comment: @ArchDevil so if you **copy-paste the EXACT same code** from the link, you get the error? Re-install your compiler or change it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Now i use Netbean and it work fine! Thanks again ^^